# Collecting data about product in cookie using Jquery

Tags: jquery, cookies

I would like to check if cookie exist and if not create one which will collect information about last 3 products seen on the page (url, picture). 
When visitor will come back I would like to show him inside slider these three products. 
Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cookie framework from mozilla.org:

[cookie_framework MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie/Simple_document.cookie_framework)

```
/*\
|*|
|*|  :: cookies.js ::
|*|
|*|  A complete cookies reader/writer framework with full unicode support.
|*|
|*|  Revision #1 - September 4, 2014
|*|
|*|  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie
|*|  https://developer.mozilla.org/User:fusionchess
|*|  https://github.com/madmurphy/cookies.js
|*|
|*|  This framework is released under the GNU Public License, version 3 or later.
|*|  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0-standalone.html
|*|
|*|  Syntaxes:
|*|
|*|  * docCookies.setItem(name, value[, end[, path[, domain[, secure]]]])
|*|  * docCookies.getItem(name)
|*|  * docCookies.removeItem(name[, path[, domain]])
|*|  * docCookies.hasItem(name)
|*|  * docCookies.keys()
|*|
\*/

var docCookies = {
  getItem: function (sKey) {
    if (!sKey) { return null; }
    return decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1")) || null;
  },
  setItem: function (sKey, sValue, vEnd, sPath, sDomain, bSecure) {
    if (!sKey || /^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/i.test(sKey)) { return false; }
    var sExpires = "";
    if (vEnd) {
      switch (vEnd.constructor) {
        case Number:
          sExpires = vEnd === Infinity ? "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT" : "; max-age=" + vEnd;
          break;
        case String:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd;
          break;
        case Date:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd.toUTCString();
          break;
      }
    }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(sValue) + sExpires + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "") + (bSecure ? "; secure" : "");
    return true;
  },
  removeItem: function (sKey, sPath, sDomain) {
    if (!this.hasItem(sKey)) { return false; }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "");
    return true;
  },
  hasItem: function (sKey) {
    if (!sKey) { return false; }
    return (new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=")).test(document.cookie);
  },
  keys: function () {
    var aKeys = document.cookie.replace(/((?:^|\s*;)[^\=]+)(?=;|$)|^\s*|\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?(?:\1|$)/g, "").split(/\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?;\s*/);
    for (var nLen = aKeys.length, nIdx = 0; nIdx < nLen; nIdx++) { aKeys[nIdx] = decodeURIComponent(aKeys[nIdx]); }
    return aKeys;
  }
};
```

Example:

```
docCookies.setItem("test0", "Hello world!");
docCookies.setItem("test1", "Unicode test: \u00E0\u00E8\u00EC\u00F2\u00F9", Infinity);
docCookies.setItem("test2", "Hello world!", new Date(2020, 5, 12));
docCookies.setItem("test3", "Hello world!", new Date(2027, 2, 3), "/blog");
docCookies.setItem("test4", "Hello world!", "Wed, 19 Feb 2127 01:04:55 GMT");
docCookies.setItem("test5", "Hello world!", "Fri, 20 Aug 88354 14:07:15 GMT", "/home");
docCookies.setItem("test6", "Hello world!", 150);
docCookies.setItem("test7", "Hello world!", 245, "/content");
docCookies.setItem("test8", "Hello world!", null, null, "example.com");
docCookies.setItem("test9", "Hello world!", null, null, null, true);
docCookies.setItem("test1;=", "Safe character test;=", Infinity);

alert(docCookies.keys().join("\n"));
alert(docCookies.getItem("test1"));
alert(docCookies.getItem("test5"));
docCookies.removeItem("test1");
docCookies.removeItem("test5", "/home");
alert(docCookies.getItem("test1"));
alert(docCookies.getItem("test5"));
alert(docCookies.getItem("unexistingCookie"));
alert(docCookies.getItem());
alert(docCookies.getItem("test1;="));
```